# Removing conky drop shadow

Tags: 11.04, compiz, conky

I've started using Conky with 11.04 and want to remove its drop shadow.

I've tried setting `any & !(class=Conky)` in the `Shadow Windows` text box of the `Window Decoration` section. This works. However, every time I try and use either the global menu or an app indicator menu, compiz crashes. Not all the time, it seems quite random on which menu it chooses to crash on, but it happens enough to not use this method.

So I was just wondering if there was any other way of removing the shadow from the Conky window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve these problems, don't paste the settings for opening in a new window, just delete the code.

---

What to delete (usually if you copied the code, it has this):

```
#Create own window instead of using desktop (required in nautilus)
own_window yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,skip_taskbar
background no
```

Comment: `draw_shades = false,`

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need is to replace
`own_window_type normal`
with
`own_window_type override` .

Answer (score 5):

The following setting in `.conkyrc` solves the shadow problem.

```
own_window_type     override
```

But causes distorted fonts and plots over time.

The following options in `.conkyrc` solved the problem for me:

```
own_window_type desktop
own_window_argb_visual yes
```

Comment: The second set configurations worked for me with nautilus. I didn't use the `own_window_type override` configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're editing settings (the `Window Decoration` section of what?) but I have `draw_shades no` in my .conkyrc and no drop shadows. [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/search/conky/) has a whole thread of Conky configs, too. Might be worth digging around there if you're trying to fine tune things.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was using the Compiz Config Settings Manager. I already have `draw_shades no` in my .conkyrc file, but it doesn't do anything. Can't see anything straight away in the lifehacker page, but I'll continue searching.

Comment: @Josh, I'm still on 10.04, but my settings for `Window Decoration > Shadow Windows` and `Window Decoration > Decoration Windows` are both "any."

Answer (score 1):

this worked better for me:

```
...
own_window          yes
own_window_type     desktop
own_window_hints    undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer       yes
no_buffers          yes
...
```

The accepted answer caused Tint2 to flicker/occasionally restart

Answer (score 0):

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
```