# Conky dropping shadow when invoked at startup

Tags: 12.04, compiz, conky

I read this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37519/removing-conky-drop-shadow) but it doesn't really address my issue. The problem that I have is that whenever I log in, conky starts up, as set up in Startup Applications, but the instance it runs is dropping shadow and is above every other window, showing the wallpaper beneath it. This can be easily fixed by relaunching conky, but that defeats the purpose of having it start up at login. Also, running conky at any point manually after logging does not cause this. Any suggestions? I rewrote the script and played about with Compiz, but it still keeps happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using "conky -p 50" in Startup Applications?

It means there will be a lag of 50 seconds before Conky is actually started and gives all other programs the opportunity to start smoothly before conky is run.
Solved a lot of issues for me.

Might be worth to try...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It's caused by conky starting up before the window manager. Most solutions will have you set conky to start 30s after boot. I found a very nifty little script that works like a charm:

```
#!/bin/bash
until ps -A | grep "gtk-window-deco"> test -n 
do 
    sleep 1 
done
/usr/bin/conky --quiet --config=.conkyrc &
```

Simply copy that into a text editor and save it as 'conkystartup.sh' (without quotes) into whatever directory suites you.

Then, add the path to the .sh file in 'Startup Applications'.

It works perfectly for me, and shows up right when you log in.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1707947

Comment: FYI: I use Ubuntu 12.04 with the "GNOME Classic" desktop. There is no process `gtk-window-deco`, so I use the static delay.